# "Invalid Binding Handle" while debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, windows-8

I've assembled my new PC yesterday, and I've decided to give Windows 8 a try. However, today, during the debugging of moderate Qt application, debugger yielded "Invalid Binding Handle" error message on a pretty simple line (it was line that is auto-generated by Qt's moc.exe:

```
 // QWebView *view (...)
 view->setUrl(QUrl(QString::fromUtf8("about:blank")));
 // Failing in setUrl call, not in QUrl constructor, or in fromUtf8 function.
```

However, running this application without debugger works just fine, both in Release and Debug versions.

I've got some clues on the internet to enable Terminal Services, but it seems that there is no such service in Windows 8.

Does anybody have any clue what should I check?

**Edit**

Moving the widget into other application yielded no error, so apparently, widget (which is pretty small - just `QWebView` and `QProgressBar`) is fine. But, when I show this widget in my main function:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
MyWidget w;
w.show();
return app.exec();
```

it is still failing with the same error. Examining call stack (which is not very helpful when error appear) and stepping into function calls, I've tracked error down to `retval = HeapFree(_crtheap, 0, pBlock);` in function `_free_base`, in file `free.c` And it seems that function is called from `dbgdel.cpp`, function `_free_dbg( pUserData, pHead->nBlockUse );` and it is called from `unlock()` function.

Attaching the debugger to already active process is still yielding the same error.

I am linking a lot of 3rd party libraries here, so I will try without them, as I'm run out of ideas...

**Edit 2:**

If I pass this exception to the program, it seems to be running fine.

**Edit 3**

Commenting setUrl line raises the same exception somewhere in `QWebKit`, where `strdup` function is called...

Comment: I guess the about: protocol handler is gone in Windows 8 (just as there is a http: or a file: protocol handler)

Comment: Unfortunately (or fortunately), this is not the case. Changing address to `http://www.google.com` does not fix the error.

Comment: Can you split it in the 3 statements? Is fromUtf8, QUrl or setUrl failing?

Comment: I've split it into 3 statements, and it seems that setUrl is failing. If I step into code, line that is causing this is `retval = HeapFree(_crtheap, 0, pBlock);` in function `_free_base`, in file `free.c` And it seems that function is called from `dbgdel.cpp`, function `_free_dbg( pUserData, pHead->nBlockUse );`, so I guess it is connected to the debugger. I will try to debug by attaching to the process.

Comment: Attaching to the process is still yielding the error. I will try to reproduce problem on a very simple program.

Comment: Well, it seems that this is not strictly connected to the Windows 8, but to my application, as separating QWidget into application is working properly... Oh, well - back to the drawing board...

Comment: If `retval = HeapFree(_crtheap, 0, pBlock);` fails, it usually means that your application has memory management problems. For example, somewhere you overwrite a memory, that has already freed. And actual problem is not at line `setUrl(...)`. Does a release version work fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this was easy, but it took me two months to solve (while ignoring the error in the meantime).

This was not an unhandled exception - this was handled exception, and stepping into assembly code and watching the stack frame told me that this exception was handled.

Then I remembered that I've set debugger to break when all C++ and Win32 exceptions are raised. Resetting the debugger settings removed the issue.

Comment: Another reason that gives the same symptom under roughly the same circumstances, is that [the 'Terminal Services' service is not running](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2006/01/04/509243.aspx). The solution is to make sure it is running. Simply starting the service without restart of the computer may be enough (it was in my case).